# Trying to print a form with a shortcode

Tags: 7, forms

I'm currently working on a drupal module and I want to print a specific form called by a shortcode. So I've use [this tuto](http://www.briannadeleasa.com/blog/drupal-php/shortcodes-drupal-yes-you-can) and here is my code :

Info :

```
    function custom_shortcodes_shortcode_info() {
      $shortcodes['form'] = array(
        'title' => t('Link form'), 
        'description' => t('A simple form.'), 
        'process callback' => 'custom_shortcodes_shortcode_form',
      );
      return $shortcodes;
    }
```

Callback:

```
    function custom_shortcodes_shortcode_form($attrs, $text) {
      $attrs = drupal_get_form('custom_shortcodes_shortcode_form_attributes');
      return $attrs;
    }
```

Form :

```
    function custom_shortcodes_shortcode_form_attributes() {
      $form = array();
      $form['PrjLogement'] = array(
        '#type' => 'textfield',
        '#title' => t('Field1'),
        '#required' => TRUE
      );

      $form['MenageRevenuM'] = array(
        '#type' => 'textfield',
        '#title' => t('Field2'),
        '#required' => TRUE
      );

      $form['MenageApport'] = array(
        '#type' => 'textfield',
        '#title' => t('Field3'),
        '#required' => TRUE
      );

      $form['submit'] = array(
        '#type'=>'submit',
        '#value'=>t('Submit')
      );

      return $form;
    }
```

Now the thing is that every time I'm calling the form with the specific shortcode the output is just "Array".
Is there any way to print this form ?
Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically, drupal_get_form doesn't render the array - it just returns the renderable array from the form function. You need to render it yourself.

Try this:

```
function custom_shortcodes_shortcode_form($attrs, $text) {
  $form = drupal_get_form('custom_shortcodes_shortcode_form_attributes');
  $attrs = drupal_render($form);
  return $attrs;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your help, I've tried this, its better : I see my form but it's not rendered as a form but more like a text. Do you know how to see it as a form ?

Comment: Drupal might be removing tags from the shortcode. Make sure that shortcodes is under 'Limit Allowed Html Tags' in your Filter Processing Order.

Comment: Thanks you very much, that was the issue, it's working great now.